# Prove this wonderful trigonometric limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\cot(\frac{x}{n+1})-\cot(\frac{x}{n-1}))=\frac{2}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, infinity

Show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\cot(\frac{x}{n+1})-\cot(\frac{x}{n-1}))=\frac{2}{x}$$

One way to prove is using series but I am wondering is there any other way to prove it . Can anyone suggest me any ideas on how to solve it without series . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Why not $\cot(x)+\cot(y)=\dots$?

Comment: leads to $$2 \cos \left(\frac{x}{n^2-1}\right) \csc \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right) \csc \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right) \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2 n-2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{2 n+2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{x}{2 n+2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{2 n-2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: $\cot(a)-\cot(b)=-\csc (a) \csc (b) \sin (a-b)$

Comment: Then how can I find the limit ?

Comment: $\cot(\alpha) - \cot(\beta) = \frac{2\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)-\cos(\alpha-\beta)}$

Comment: If you assume that $n$ is large enough to use the [small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) for the cotangent arguments, then $\cot\theta \approx \frac{1}{\theta}$, then the result follows from that.

Answer (score 3):

$$\cot\left(\frac x{n+1}\right)-\cot\left(\frac x{n-1}\right)=\int_{\frac x{n+1}}^{\frac x{n-1}}\csc^2t\,dt\tag1$$
and for $x>0$
$$\frac{\frac {2x}{n^2-1}}{\sin^2(\frac x{n-1})}\leq \int_{\frac x{n+1}}^{\frac x{n-1}}\csc^2t\,dt\leq\frac{\frac {2x}{n^2-1}}{\sin^2(\frac x{n+1})}\tag2$$
By squeeze theorem, $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cot\left(\frac x{n+1}\right)-\cot\left(\frac x{n-1}\right)=\frac 2x.$ Similarly for $x<0.$

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but at least you don't have to use the entire Taylor series. If you are generous with the Big O notation it is pretty quick, $\cot(x) = \frac{1}{x+O(x^3)}$ as $x \to 0$ we have that

\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} \cot\left(\tfrac{x}{n+1}\right)-\cot\left(\tfrac{x}{n-1}\right)&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n+1}+O(\tfrac{1}{n^3})} - \frac{1}{\frac{x}{n+1}+O(\tfrac{1}{n^3})} \right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{x+O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})} - \frac{n-1}{x+O(\tfrac{1}{n^2})} \right)\\ &= \frac{2}{x + \lim_{n\to \infty}O(1/n^2)} = \frac{2}{x}.\\ \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

If one has fun in trigonometry

$$\cot \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)-\cot \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right) \sin \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 x}{n^2-1}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right) \sin \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)}=\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{n^2-1}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{n^2-1}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right) \sin \left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)} \to \frac{2 x}{\frac{\left(n^2-1\right) x^2}{n^2-1}}\to \frac{2}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

A little tedious but using the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) also works. In particular, the $\psi$ function satisfies the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula),
$$\cot z=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{z}{\pi}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)\right)$$
we have,
$$\cot\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi(n+1)}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{x}{\pi(n+1)}\right)\right) \\
\cot\left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi(n-1)}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{x}{\pi(n-1)}\right)\right)$$
then,
$$\cot\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{x}{n-1}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}(A-B)$$
where
$$A=\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi(n+1)}\right)-\psi\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi(n-1)}\right) \\
B=\psi\left(\frac{x}{\pi(n+1)}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{x}{\pi(n-1)}\right)$$
taking limits,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A=\psi(1)-\psi(1)=0.$$
$B$ is a little more difficult as the $\psi$ function has a pole at zero, but by Taylor's formula,
$$\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\frac{\pi^2}{6}z+O(z^2)$$
as $z\to0$, and upon using the [functional relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers) $\psi(z+1)=\psi(z)+1/z$ we find,
$$\psi(z)=-\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+O(z)$$
as $z\to 0$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). Substitute,
$$B=\frac{\pi(n-1)}{x}-\frac{\pi(n+1)}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\frac{2}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
as $n\to\infty$, hence,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A-B}{\pi}=\frac{2}{x}.$$

---

As an intuition for this approach, note that this method seeks to remove the divergent $-1/z$ term in the Laurent expansion of $\psi(z)$.

Answer (score -1):

I can show an intuitive proof:
as $x \to 0$ $\tan(x)=x$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cot(\frac{x}{n+1})-\cot(\frac{x}{n-1})=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{x}{n+1})}-\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{x}{n-1})}$$
$$\cot(\frac{x}{n+1})-\cot(\frac{x}{n-1})=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{x}{n+1})}-\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{x}{n-1})}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{x}-\frac{n-1}{x}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)-(n-1)}{x}=\frac{2}{x}$$
the actual proof involves a lot of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$
hope I helped!

I think you typed something wrong

Comment: you shouldn't invert the argument inside the cotangents when inverting

Comment: Can you please explain the step where you get $\frac{n+1}{x}$ from $\frac{1}{tan(\frac{n+1}{x})}$.

Comment: @jack625 i guess he wrote it incorrectly but $\cot(\frac{x}{n+1})= \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{x}{n+1})} \approx \frac{1}{\frac{x}{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{x}$

Comment: @grimm that's why I wrote that I think he wrote something wrong

Comment: @MichaelMorad you are the one who wrote it wrong. You wrote $cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{1}{x})}$ which is incorrect.

Comment: @grimm 